# React Hot Reload 3 Not showing updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

I've just upgraded to Webpack 2.2.0 and followed the documentation for adding hot reloading: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/ The weird thing is that when I make a change, I get this in the console:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client:38 [WDS] App hot update...
dev-server.js:45 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log-apply-result.js:20 [HMR] Updated modules:
log-apply-result.js:22 [HMR]  - ./app/components/Main/InstancePropertiesDialog.jsx
log-apply-result.js:22 [HMR]  - ./app/containers/Main/InstancesList.jsx
log-apply-result.js:22 [HMR]  - ./app/config/router.jsx
log-apply-result.js:22 [HMR]  - ./app/App.jsx
dev-server.js:27 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

And no errors. But the changes don't show up and the window doesn't reload automatically as it would with only live reload. In order to see any change, I need to refresh the page. Am I missing something to install? Thank you.

- Maybe it is worth mentioning that I am using react-router and redux

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was? I'm struggling with the same issue now.